# List of checkboxes are lost when the form is submitted

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have these viewmodels for employees and their roles:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // some more properties
    public List<EmployeeRoleViewModel> EmployeeRoles { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeRoleViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

I am displaying the checkboxes like this in the Edit-view:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.EmployeeRoles.Count(); i++)
{
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.EmployeeRoles[i].Selected" />
    @Model.EmployeeRoles[i].Title
</label>
}
```

This generates this HTML for a checked checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" 
    id="EmployeeRoles_0__Selected" 
    name="EmployeeRoles[0].Selected" value="true" />
```

... and this for an unchecked one:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
    id="EmployeeRoles_2__Selected" 
    name="EmployeeRoles[2].Selected" value="true" />
```

The checkboxes are all being rendered correctly, with checkmarks on all the right boxes.

The form is posted to this controller-method (simplified for brevity):

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id,[Bind("Id,EmployeeRoles")] Employee employee)
{
    db.Update(employee);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction("Details", "Branches");
}
```

The problem is that `employee.EmployeeRoles` is a list of length 0, even though several checkboxes are checked. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `name` of the `input` field will have to be

`name="Employee.EmployeeRoles[index].Selected"`

in order for `EmployeeRoles[index]` to be bound to the `EmployeeRoles` list inside the `Employee` object.

Answer (score 0):

Please firstly confirm that you are using same view model both in view and in action function . You can add hidden input field to help you bind the properties :

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.EmployeeRoles.Count(); i++)
{
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.EmployeeRoles[i].Selected" />
        @Model.EmployeeRoles[i].Title
    </label>

    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.EmployeeRoles[i].Id" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.EmployeeRoles[i].Title" />
}
```

Then on controller , you can get the lists :
[image]

Then check the `Selected` properties to confirm whether current role is selected .